# Should the questions of identifying language be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/language-used-in-escrava-isaura-opening-theme) has been recently asked.

Should questions about identifying languages be on-topic here?

**Pro's**

- Such Q's are often interesting by themselves;
- They may highlight some unusual usage of common languages or provide an interesting info about extinct or rare ones;
- They may let the users to demonstrate their erudition (may be an important concern for someone);
- At the moment, Linguistics.SE [needs more users and more questions](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/463/1009), so even if such questions are not {yet} on-topic, they may be included;

**Con's**

- There may be disputes on which language it is, provided that several relative languages or dialects may apply;
- They are not about linguistics! :)

Comment: Thanks for the question. I'll wait to see more community participation and then when there's enough consensus, I'll take the majority vote. :) I added the `featured` tag. It should bring more attention to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is now out of date.

Comment: @curiousdannii, how does that help? Would it not be more helpful to answer it instead, referencing current policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: in the years since this was written, the community has since decided that [**these questions are no longer allowed**](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1747/2555).

---

As you say, there are several good reasons to allow them, and that is enough for me. I vote yes.

Answer (score 1):

Few considerations:

- Methods of automated language identification given a text belong to linguistics. So language identification per se is not off-topic, but just this particular type of language identification as it includes listening to a recorded speech sample.
- Sometimes identified language family or even a geographic area could be enough for the asker

Also it is not clear to me how language identification should be performed in principle. A web site where speakers of all possible languages listen to all samples provided by askers doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: RE: automated identification, I would argue that Markov's chains and Vector-space modeling rather belong to [Theoretical Comp Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/); there are many nice NLP questions there.

Comment: RE: how identification should be done. Again, it's a statistical analysis combined with a probabilistic Vector-space modeling, like on [this site](http://labs.translated.net/language-identifier/).

Answer (score 0):

More questions is ok with me!

And if there are some disputes about exactly which dialect/language it is then I look forward to some well argued linguistic analysis.